# Prove integrability of a function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I've been trying to solve this but with no luck, and couldn't find anything online.
The problem is:

Let $f(x)$ be a riemann integrable function over the interval $[a,b]$. Show that the function $e^{f(x)}$ is integrable over the interval $[a,b]$.

Thank you!!

Comment: By integrable, do you mean Riemann integrable or Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: Riemann integrable

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about Lebesgue integration this is false. $-ln x$ is integrable on $(0,1)$ but $e^{-\ln x}$ is not integrable.

If you are talking about Riemann integration this follows from the fact that a bounded  function is Riemann integrable iff it is continuous almost everywhere.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but the question is about a closed interval [a,b] where in your example -lnx is integrable on an open interval (0,1). Is it still ok to assume that?

Comment: @Orokusaki For Riemann  integral I am using the closed interval. For Lebesgue integral there is no difference between open and closed intervals since every single point has Lebesgue measure $0$. If you want you extend the definition of my function by taking $f(x) =-\ln x$ for $0 <1 \leq 1$ and $f(0)=0$.